# Spring Security / expired-url no redirect url

Tags: java, web, concurrency, spring-security

Hi Im working with Spring and I have a problem trying to use concurrency-control and authentication-failure-url.

I try to do that the same user can not login in the aplication concurrently. So for that, I defined the concurrency-control in security.xml as:

```
<concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/login_page?login_timeout=1"/>
```

My idea is when the second user will try to login, the login page should be called with:

- login_page?login_max_session_exceed=1"

I have a form-login too as:

```
<form-login login-page="/login_page" default-target-url="/index.jsp"
        authentication-failure-url="/login_page?login_error=1" />
```

But the problem that I have is when I try to login the second user, ALWAYS, the login page is called with

- login_page?login_error=1"   (the expired-url is not redirect)

What is the problem? How can I do to use the expired-url redirect when the second user try to connect.

The version of the spring that I using are:

Spring.core 3.2.8 and Spring.security 3.2.3

My web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Sistema de Despacho de Contingencia Acindar</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sdca-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sdca-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener> 

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>

</listener>

<!-- Spring Security -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/sdca-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

My security.xml

```
    <http auto-config="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login_page" default-target-url="/index.jsp"
        authentication-failure-url="/login_page?login_error=1" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login_page?logout=1" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
        <session-management invalid-session-url="/login_page"
        session-authentication-error-url="/login_page?login_max_session_exceed=1">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
            error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/login_page?login_timeout=1"/>
    </session-management>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login_page" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
</http>
```

Thank for you help!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bit of confusion about some of the configuration options here. To start with, the `expired-url` attribute is not relevant, since you are treating multiple logins as an error. It only applies if you permit a second login which will then cause the first to be "expired". Check out the documentation for [the namespace configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-concurrency-control).

The `session-authentication-error-url` attribute doesn't apply here either. To quote from [the manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-session-mgmt):

> The second login will then be rejected. By “rejected”, we mean that the user will be **sent to the authentication-failure-url if form-based login is being used**. If the second authentication takes place through another non-interactive mechanism, such as “remember-me”, an “unauthorized” (402) error will be sent to the client. If instead you want to use an error page, you can add the attribute `session-authentication-error-url` to the session-management element.

So it is only used if something like remember-me authentication is used.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But session-authentication-error-url doesn't work if there's authentication-failure-url defined. So How Do I for that "/login_page?login_max_session_exceed=1" works? Is posible ?

Comment: You can use a custom `AuthenticationFailureHandler` to control where the user is redirected depending on whether failure is due to a concurrent login (when you will get a `SessionAuthenticationException`) or some other reason. However, you should also probably clarify what you are actually trying to do.